# What is a thing called that takes measurements?

Tags: single-word-requests

A measurer? *Doesn't pronounce well*

A sensor? *Doesn't work because there's a simple counterexample that a ruler takes measurements without being a sensor*

Specifically, I'm looking for a word that can be used as a name for a software component that produces measurements.

Comment: It depends on what you measure but a general term is a [measuring instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_instrument).

Comment: If it measures anything electricly or electronically, it's a _meter_. Probly that word could be combined with just about anything: _depth meter, RPM meter, speedometer, water meter, electric meter,_ etc.

Comment: If you want something that encompasses yardsticks, voltmeters, stream gauges, and calipers, I think you need to use *measuring apparatus*. But I think *meter* would work fine for your application.

Comment: I agree with *meter* generally. However, if it can be inserted and removed, I believe *probe* is more descriptive. And if it is only counting, *counter* is more apt. Also, if it is actually collecting/gathering data, then you can consider *data recorder* as well. Finally, in software, I have seen such components referred to as a *statistic*, or *stat*, even though it is a misnomer.

Comment: Feeding *software component that produces measurements* into Google  (books) yielded: [Publisher](https://books.google.com/books?id=qhHsSlazGrQC&pg=PA1165&lpg=PA1165&dq=software+component+that+produces+measurements&source=bl&ots=TiNnZzpiFl&sig=5s3heIopUpSJEJQHF8JVUlrd2G0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6MtaVaTLCoehyQSH84DABQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=software%20component%20that%20produces%20measurements&f=false) "a publisher is a sensor that produces measurements." -The Electrical Engineering Handbook

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A **meter** (as opposed to *metre*).

Or a **gauge**.

Comment: +1 for *gauge*.  *Meter* can be confusing in American English (because we don't have *metre*) and is almost never used to mean *something with which you measure*.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: It depends on context, I suppose. It will probably work for a software component...

Comment: I usually hear *meter* used as either the unit or as the musical term.  I've never heard it to mean a *gauge*, which is, in my opinion, exactly the right word for OP.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - When I hear "meter" I instantly think of the round thing with a needle waving back and forth.  But then I'm tone deaf and couldn't count time with a digitized metronome.

Comment: @Cerberus, George and the science of measurement is called *metrology* - as I know from my metrologist flatmate!

Comment: @George Pompidou: Google NGrams offers no support for your assertion - at least in respect of *(electrical) [current meter/gauge*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=current+meter%2Ccurrent+gauge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurrent%20meter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurrent%20gauge%3B%2Cc0). (Actually, it's the same for a *camera light meter*, but I can't fit two links into one comment! :)

Comment: Add one for *meter* (I can't start a comment with +1) and *gauge* as a freebie extra.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - Can't understand why you think "meter" wouldn't work in AmE.   As John Lawler pointed out in his comment "'sth' meter" is very common. (Although he forgot my favorite: sphygmomanometer.)

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: In this context, the term *meter* is the same as the ***gas meter***, or the ***electric meter***, or what the taxi cab runs to track the fare due, which is commonly used in AmE. But, I do associate it mostly with things that figure out usage for the purpose of billing (a electricity meter will report the peak usage for a billing period, and your bill reflects that). OTOH, a *speedometer* is a type of ***gauge***. On the one hand, it is an instantaneous measure, but in software, this is usually computed with a moving average.

Comment: I would argue that a meter is an *active* measuring instrument. As John Lawler points out, you wouldn't call a yardstick a "meter" (nor even a meter stick, unless you meant that was its size, obviously). A "meter" is a thing that counts or otherwise itself determines some measurement, rather than simply helping you determine it passively. +ermanen's recommendation of (measuring) instrument, which doesn't care whether it's active or passive measuring - that said, if it's software, it's probably active measuring, so meter would work fine.

Comment: @Oldbag - My favorite is extinctionspectrophotopoleriscopeocculogravogyrokynetometer.  (Though for some reason the spell checker isn't happy with it.)

Comment: Every example of *meter* usage you guys gave comes with an accompanying word to support it, like *gas meter* etc. That's good and all but it doesn't work on it's own.  *What's that?* / *A meter* to me doesn't communicate anything about a measuring device.

Comment: Think of the statement *bring me a meter which can measure X*. To me it's not quite as clear as *bring me a gauge which can measure X*.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: It's been a while ago, but check these quotations: https://www.google.nl/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1996%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=inaccurate+meter&oq=inaccurate+meter&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.12516.14525.0.14667.16.14.0.0.0.0.246.1275.6j3j2.11.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.5.601...0j0i13.jC5esLxZRag

Comment: @Cerberus I stand by my claim. I've never heard the word *meter* being used *by itself* to mean this. *Gas meter*, *speedometer*, *billy bob meter*, *inaccurate meter* all work fine, but just the word *meter* by itself means 100cm to me and doesn't make me think of any gadget or physical device.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: All right, then how about these quotations: https://www.google.nl/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1996%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=inaccurate+meter&oq=inaccurate+meter&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.12516.14525.0.14667.16.14.0.0.0.0.246.1275.6j3j2.11.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.5.601...0j0i13.jC5esLxZRag#q=%22use+a+meter%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&tbas=0

Comment: @Cerberus You'll notice that many of them are "use a meter stick" or "use a meter rule" which makes sense to me.  Also, many of them at first glance are in *heavy* context.  If we're already talking about measuring electric field, for example, and we've used something to measure it and someone says "let's use a meter that provides better x" that makes sense to me too.

Comment: @Cerberus But even with all that said, you cannot compare an online lookup of books to my personal experience living in the United States for over half my life.  For example, I'm sure you can find the word *solicitor* used to mean *attorney* in many, many books.  It also makes sense in day to day use in the UK.  But if you simply and out of context use the word *solicitor* in the US, an average person will assume you mean someone who is trying to get your business.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: But why does that matter? I'm not particularly concerned with American usage, just British or standard.

Comment: @Cerberus Well, my initial comment on this post was just to throw in my two cents/perspective on the matter.  Then I got called out and had to defend myself.

Comment: @Cerberus Also, I think you'll find many more people are concerned with American English than with British English.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: Sure, I don't think I was calling you out until you pang me. As to a number of people, does that matter? At any rate, it's hard to claim that one's own intuitions represent an entire country's dialect/accent/variant...

Comment: @Cerberus I didn't mean to say that my intuitions represent anything more than my intuitions.  I didn't mean to shed light on anything more than my perspective.  If you look up, you'll see that my first two posts were just that, me sharing my perspective, followed by 4 people making arguments against it.  Then it became this nonsense.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: Haha, okay. I didn't read the comment history this time.

Answer (score 11):

Instrument.

1.a tool or implement, especially one for delicate or scientific work.

2.a measuring device used to gauge the level, position, speed, etc., of something, especially a motor vehicle or aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on context.

Although other answers suggest generic words like *meter*, *gauge*, *instrument*, etc. those words are not commonly used in practice.

More typically, we refer to the specific name of the *device* being used to take the measurements.

For example, a device that measures length might be a ***ruler***. Or a ***yardstick***. Or a ***tape measure***. Or a ***caliper***. Depending on the size and shape of the object and how accurate we need the measurement to be. A device used to measure weight is a ***scale***. Or a ***balance***. To measure current through a wire, we use an ***ammeter***. To measure resistance, we use an ***ohmmeter***. For voltage, a ***voltmeter***. To measure speed we use a ***speedometer*** (from inside the vehicle) or a ***radar gun*** (from outside the vehicle or object). And so on.

So, to get the best answer, you should specify exactly what you are trying to measure.